# git can't pull the added files

Tags: git

scenario: I have a remote branch on a server called trip, and two local branches -both named trip- on two different locations ,updating the above mentioned remote branch.
 (both locals are in the same state)

problem,
I just created two more files in one of the local branches, then commited and pushed it to remote branch
Now I need to pull those file from remote branch to the other local branch. but when I say

```
git pull origin trip
```

it says the branch is already uptodate.

How can i get the files please?
thank you

Comment: How did you push your changes to the remote branch? And on which branch ? Can you show us exact command how you pushed!

Comment: @roko tribbly sorry, forgot to push :) will close this post momntarily, thanks